# Turn Off Parenthesis Matching in Sublime Text 2

Tags: text-editing, sublime-text-2

I have questions about turn off parenthesis matching. Does anyone know how to turn off parenthesis matching?

example:

When I type a `(`, it will automatically add `)`, becomes `()`.

It's pretty nice for editing plain text. But quite annoying while editing clojure files.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Set this in your User settings

```
"auto_match_enabled" : false
```

Comment: Can you make it a toggle switch?

Comment: You'd be better off adding that line to the User settings (Preferences > Settings - User) rather than global so that they're not overwritten by updates.

Answer (score 10):

You can toggle this setting by adding a key binding to 'Preferences > Key Bindings - User'.
e.g. to make  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> toggle the setting, use:

```
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+shift+p"],
    "command": "toggle_setting",
    "args":
    {
        "setting": "auto_match_enabled"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you need to change autoMatchEnabled to false under File Type Preferences to disable auto pairing. Read more about it: http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/file-type-preferences

Comment: Thanks Sam! it should be there. But I set "autoMatchEnabled":false @Global.sublime-settings, restart, still not working.