# How to turn off Sublime Text's auto_match_enabled for a specific set of delimiters in specific sorts of documents?

Tags: latex, sublime-text

My question is [related to this question about turning off parenthesis matching in Sublime Text 2](https://superuser.com/questions/392200/turn-off-parenthesis-matching-in-sublime-text-2).

Sublime Text 2/3 has the setting "auto_match_enabled", which automatically pairs delimiters ([ ],{ }," ", etc.). Most of the time this is a great feature. When writing certain documents, however, it gets in the way.

For instance, in LaTeX the double quotes are used (almost?) exclusively to add in umlauts. So, e.g., `n\"aive` gets compiled as `näive`. In this situation the automatic insertion of the matching double quote is not helpful -- it adds a keystroke to delete it. Given this, I would like to turn off auto matching *only for double quotes* and *only in files with a `.tex` extension*. Unfortunately, the global setting seems like an all-or-nothing deal -- there is no obvious (to me) way to restrict its scope.

How do I turn off auto matching for a single type of delimiter in a given context? More specifically, how do I turn off auto matching for double quotes in files with a `.tex` extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Jonno's answer above, you can modify the keymap settings for a given package in the same way:

Create a `Default.sublime-keymap` file in the LaTeX directory (create folders if needed):

```
Windows:
%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\LaTeX\Default.sublime-keymap

macOS:
~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/LaTeX/Default.sublime-keymap

Linux:
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/LaTeX/Default.sublime-keymap
```

You can then copy & paste the default keymap (`Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default`) settings for double quotes into this new file. Then I modified the actions of those key bindings to no longer insert quoted pairs. This is the result of my changes:

```json
[
    // changed snippet arg contents from `"\"$0\""` to `"\""` to prevent inserting paired quotes
    { "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\""}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^(?:\t| |\\)|]|\\}|>|$)", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_contains", "operand": "[\"a-zA-Z0-9_]$", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true }
        ]
    },
    // changed the command and args from `move` to the same command/args as above to prevent skipping auto-inserted quotes
    { "keys": ["\""], "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "\""}, "context":
        [
            { "key": "setting.auto_match_enabled", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
            { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
            { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^\"", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "punctuation.definition.string.begin", "match_all": true },
            { "key": "eol_selector", "operator": "not_equal", "operand": "string.quoted.double - punctuation.definition.string.end", "match_all": true },
        ]
    }
]
```

Notes:

- I did not change the `backspace` operator (seen in the default keymap) when surrounded by quotes. I'm not exactly sure how to fix or if the behavior is incorrect or not
- Your default keybindings may be different than mine, feel free to make the same changes I described in comments above
- I imagine you can remove the entire `context` section and it work, but I did not try that out myself.

Comment: I’ve just been living with this issue, thanks for bringing this question back from the dead, oh wise necromancer.

Comment: Used a similar solution for Sublime Text 2 for Lisp files, to prevent auto completion of single quotes. I copied the  `Preferences -> Key Bindings - Default` to `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/Lisp/Default.sublime-keymap` and edited the `//Auto-pair single quotes section`, changing snippet arg contents from `"'$0'"` to `"'"`

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid I don't have a solution for only double quotes, but if you want to disable just for LaTeX you can create the following file:

(This is for Sublime Text 3 - I believe it's similar for Sublime Text 2 though)

`%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 3\Packages\LaTeX\LaTeX.sublime-settings`

You may need to create the folder structure, and you can add any LaTeX specific settings here, in your case:

```
{
    "auto_match_enabled": false,
}
```

As I said and as I think you know, this will apply to all matching, I don't have an answer for only double quotes I'm afraid, but hopefully this will help with the LaTeX specific side.

Comment: Thanks for the partial answer! Unfortunately, I fear that the other half is going to be where things get tricky. I'll tinker a bit, but hopefully some Sublime wiz comes through with a neat trick.

Comment: @Dennis Fingers crossed :)

Comment: this worked for me. It was doing this for me using SCSS